# Multiple slidetoggles

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have question about how I add another menu item in the following code. I would like to add a contact "menu" item. I found a lot of examples but they were all examples where the items was in a list, i want them to be displayed in a line. I would like that both of them can slide down and up independently and if its possible add a close link so the user can hit that and the slide. slides up again. I hope someone in here can help me. I'm new to jquery.

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $('#about').click(function() {
   $('.about').slideToggle('fast');
  return false;
  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<h2><a href="#" id="about">About</a></h2>
<div class="about">
<h5><div class="text">
blah blah
</div></h5>
</div>
```

css:

```
#about {
margin-left: 325px;
}

.about {
display:none;
width: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
height: 351px;
padding-left: 325px;
}

.text {
padding-bottom: 35px;
padding-right: 35px;
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light';
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 30px;

/* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 30px;

column-count: 3;
column-gap: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$('h2 a').click(function(e) {
  $('.'+this.id).slideToggle('fast');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

*its possible add a close link so the user can hit that and the slide. slides up again.*

For this you can add a close link in each slides with a class like

`<a href="#" class="close">Close</a>`

and then you can add this:

```
$('.close').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('div').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick respons.. How would you write the HTML.. I have added <h2><a href="#" id="about">Contact</a></h2> but then it opens both of them when i hit about or contact... And if i change id="about" to id="contact" the contact doens't work..

Comment: That worked perfectly.. Thank you for your help.. Do you know why the text jumps when it slides? Is not a really smooth animation.. Just if you have an idea of what it could be..

Comment: There is only on problem, is it possible to have the about and contact displayed in a line instead of a list.. So contact is on the right side of about.. Thanks!